# Why is bash dynamic variable and string concatenation jumbling/overwriting my looped output?

Tags: bash, variables, sed, concatenation

I am looping through a folder containing 2 json files, extracting values from a "name" key and storing them in a variable.

I am then trying to perform some actions using those variables (eg: comparing to results of a curl request) and also print what's happening to console.

**The problem I am having is that the echo'd output of the script seems to be jumbling some of the variable and string text.  It only seems to happen in the first loop, the second loop looks OK.**

I am not sure why this is happening.  Looking the script, script output and source files below, can anybody see why my output gets jumbled this way in the first loop?  Perhaps it is my use of dynamic variables?

Script, script output and files+content below...

**Script**

```
###############################
# SETTINGS
###############################
connectorsDirectory="sources"
connectHost=localhost


###############################
# INIT
###############################

# Get a list of all currently running connectors
connectorListResponse=$(curl -s $connectHost:8083/connectors)
runningConnectorList=$(echo $connectorListResponse | sed -e 's/\[\(.*\)\]/\1/')
echo $runningConnectorList
echo "==="
# Convert runningConnectorList into something parseable by removing square brackets and double-quotes
parseableRunningConnectorList=`echo $runningConnectorList | tr -d '[]"'`
echo $parseableRunningConnectorList
echo "===="
connectorName=""
genericConnectorName=""

###############################
# JOB
###############################


# Loop through JSON files in provided connectors directory
for filename in $connectorsDirectory/*.json; do
    [ -e "$filename" ] || continue

    echo "Reading $filename ..."

    # Find connector name specified in file
    #connectorName=$(cat $filename | sed -n 's|.*"name":"\([^"]*\)".*|\1|p')
    connectorName=$(sed -nE '/name/{s/.*:\s*"(.*)",/\1/p;q}' $filename)
    #connectorNameSED='/name/{s/.*:\s*"(.*)",/\1/p;q}'
    echo "connectorName="$connectorName


    # Find "generic" connector name (sans .v### at END of string)
    genericConnectorName=$(echo "$connectorName" | sed 's/\.v[0-9]*$//')

    echo "genericConnectorName="$genericConnectorName


    if [ -z "$connectorName" ]
    then
        echo "No connector found in this file."
    else
        echo "Found connector in file named: "$filename" (generic name = "$genericConnectorName")"
    fi
    echo "---"


    # Loop through running connectors and find those that start with our "generic" connector name

    # If there are any connectors running AND we also found a connector in the current file...
    if [ ! -z "$parseableRunningConnectorList" ] && [ ! -z "$connectorName" ]
    then
        echo "Turning off the following connectors..."
        # Loop through running connectors and delete them (turn them off)
        for runningConnectorName in $(echo $parseableRunningConnectorList | sed "s/,/ /g")
        do
            connectorToTurnOff=$(echo "$runningConnectorName" | grep ^$genericConnectorName)
            if [ ! -z $connectorToTurnOff ]
            then
                echo $connectorToTurnOff
                echo "TEST MODE: curl -X DELETE $connectHost:8083/connectors/$connectorToTurnOff"
                #curl -X DELETE $connectHost:8083/connectors/$connectorToTurnOff
                #add some logic here to concat found connectors
            fi
        done
    else
        # No running connectors, so nothing to turn off ahead of publishing new connector (ie: do nothing)
        echo "No connector in this file or no running connectors needing to be stopped."
    fi

    # Publish the connector found in the current file
    if [ -z $connectorName ]
    then
        echo "No connector job to publish in the current file."
    else
        echo "Publishing connect job: \"$connectorName\"..."
        echo "TEST MODE: curl -X POST -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" --data @$filename http://$connectHost:8083/connectors"
        echo "TEST MODE: Connect job \"$connectorName\" is now active."
        #curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @$filename http://$connectHost:8083/connectors
        #echo "Connect job \"$connectorName\" is now active."
    fi
    #
    echo ""
    echo "#############################################################################"
    echo ""


done
```

**Script Output**

```
[centos@localhost test]$ ./publish_connectors.sh
"some.sink.connector.running","some.source.connector.running","cars.sales.test_v2","some.other.source.connector.v001"
===
some.sink.connector.running,some.source.connector.running,cars.sales.test_v2,some.other.source.connector.v001
====
Reading sources/stanbridge.connect.source.test.v01.json ...
connectorName=stanbridge.connect.source.test.v001
genericConnectorName=stanbridge.connect.source.test.v001
)ound connector in file named: sources/stanbridge.connect.source.test.v01.json (generic name = stanbridge.connect.source.test.v001
---
Turning off the following connectors...
"...ishing connect job: "stanbridge.connect.source.test.v001
TEST MODE: curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @sources/stanbridge.connect.source.test.v01.json http://localhost:8083/connectors
" is now active.ct job "stanbridge.connect.source.test.v001

#############################################################################

Reading sources/cars.sales.test.json ...
connectorName=cars.sales.test.v001
genericConnectorName=cars.sales.test
Found connector in file named: sources/cars.sales.test.json (generic name = cars.sales.test)
---
Turning off the following connectors...
Publishing connect job: "cars.sales.test.v001"...
TEST MODE: curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @sources/cars.sales.test.json http://localhost:8083/connectors
TEST MODE: Connect job "cars.sales.test.v001" is now active.

#############################################################################
```

**File1: sources/stanbridge.connect.source.test.v01.json**

```
{
  "name": "stanbridge.connect.source.test.v001",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
    "group.id": "stanbridge.connect.source.test.v01xxyyzza",
    "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "https://my.schema.registry",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "https://my.schema.registry",
    "key.converter.basic.auth.user.info": "someKeyString:someSecretString",
    "value.converter.basic.auth.user.info": "SsomeSString:someSecretString",
    "errors.log.enable": "true",
    "errors.log.include.messages": "true",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://my.db.host/dbName",
    "connection.user": "postgres",
    "connection.password": "postgres",
    "mode": "incrementing",
    "incrementing.column.name": "audit_id",
    "query": "SELECT customer_id, customer_name, audit_id FROM cars.customers",
    "topic.prefix": "stanbridge.connect.source.test"
  }
}
```

**File2: sources/cars.sales.test.json**

```
{"name": "cars.sales.test.v001",
  "config":     {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
    "group.id": "cars.sales.test.v001",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "https://my.schema.registry",
    "value.converter.basic.auth.credentials.source": "USER_INFO",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.basic.auth.user.info": "someKeyString:someSecretString",
    "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "https://my.schema.registry",
    "key.converter.basic.auth.credentials.source": "USER_INFO",
    "key.converter.schema.registry.basic.auth.user.info": "someKeyString:someSecretString",
    "errors.log.enable": "true",
    "errors.log.include.messages": "true",
    "tasks.max": "2",
    "batch.max.rows": "100",
    "connection.user": "postgres",
    "connection.password": "",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://my.db.host/dbName",
    "query": "SELECT car_id, field1, field2, field3, date_modified_utc FROM cars.sales",
    "mode": "timestamp",
    "timestamp.column.name": "date_modified_utc",
    "poll.interval.ms": "5000",
    "timeout.ms": "25000",
    "topic.prefix": "cars.sales.dummy",
    "transforms": "createKey",
    "transforms.createKey.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey",
    "transforms.createKey.fields": "car_id"
        }
}
```

In the script output, notice the following in the first loop...

- sed isn't removing the .v001 suffix in:
  genericConnectorName=stanbridge.connect.source.test.v001
  This works when used direct in commandline
- Text overwritten in line output beginning with: )ound connector in file named
- Text overwritten in line output beginning with: "...ishing connect job: "stanbridge.connect.source.test.v001
- Text overwritten in line output beginning with: " is now active.ct job "stanbridge.connect.source.test.v001

NB: I thought it would be easiest to understand if I included the whole script as it's not that big. Apologies if this is bad form.

Any assistance with this one is much appreciated.  Thanks!

Stanbridge

Comment: See [mcve], nobody has time to decipher this

Comment: It might be a better idea to use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) instead of sed to parse json. This and the minimal example mentioned before might help you find the problem yourself or post an easier to read question.

Comment: Thanks guys, will have a go at making a smaller example.

Answer (score 0):

@lucas FYI... using jq was indeed the answer.  I am not sure how but the sed above in my script that tries to extract the name was causing the issue, specifically:

```
connectorName=$(sed -nE '/name/{s/.*:\s*"(.*)",/\1/p;q}' $filename)
```

Much easier and problem free to use jq as follows:

```
connectorName=$(cat $filename | jq -r '.name')
```

Thanks again guys, and apologiesd for the overly verbose initial post.